# upload large files more than 300MB to azure blob storage through Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

we have an application (Java and Spring) that is hosted in azure app service and we are trying to upload large files to Azure blob through Rest API using Form data from UI. We have changed request length and API request timeout, but still we are facing connection timeout errors

Comment: COuld you please provide you code?

Comment: Welcome! As @JimXu mentioned, you'll need to edit your question to show the code you've written. Also, please include exact errors you're receiving, along with any other pertinent details. Otherwise, there's really no way to solve this problem, aside from random guesses.

Comment: Note: when you post your code, please be sure to exclude (or at least alter) any account names, account keys, etc.